# OSX ownership options for PowerPC iMac

Tags: macos, powerpc

I was given a [iMacG4 (PowerPC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMac_G4)  and intend to give to an 8 year old for the purpose of web browsing and exploring python.  I would like to gain administrative (sudo) privilege.

Although I have access as a common user, I do not have the password, which means no sudo privilege.  I also do not have the original CDs.

Does it make sense to [reset the box to factory settings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nkOy4cw_pBs) or is there a better technique to gain sudo ability?  Considering its age is the factory reset procedure different from modern Macs?

I did find this crudely written procedure from the youTube factory reset procedure:

1. Restart or Turn On Your iMac G4 or G5 Computer
2. Press <kbd>Cmd-S</kbd> at the same time when you see a black screen.
3. Root # should come up
4. When you see the root # type `mount -uw /` and press <kbd>Return</kbd>
5. Type `rm /DB/.applesetupdone` followed by <kbd>Return</kbd>
6. Your screen will come up with all these white words going down which is normal
7. It will shutdown, Turn ON your iMac G4 or G5 Computer
8. It will take a while to load up, then it should load a quick video starting with a apple logo.

I could not confirm if step 4 was performed correctly and 
Step 5 did not work because it was read only.

Comment: Do you have access to the DVDs with the OS which came with the hardware? Can you currently log in as a user but not as an administrator?

Comment: Good questions: I do not have the original CDs and yes: the machine automatically logs in as user.  I do not have the user password and therefore no sudo privilege.

Comment: I've fixed the commands. Also there seems to be something missing between 5 and 6, probably `shutdown -r -t now Bye`.

Comment: I still have a PPC OS X CD around here somewhere...if you need an image, let me know.

Comment: @Allan: Yes please: how can I download it?

Comment: Which OSX version do you need?

Comment: Download it from here [OX X 10.5 Snow Leopard](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmW50NkbWLGikphH9nt0sH2KSk7VdA)